# Limits for Triple Integration

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have 4 random variables: $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$

The joint probability distribution function of $p_1, p_2, p_3$ is:

$f(p1,p2,p3) = p_1^{b_1 + x_1 - 1} p_2^{b_2 + x_2 - 1} p_3^{b_3 + x_3 - 1} (1-p_1-p_2-p_3)^{x4+b4-1}$

where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ are positive real numbers.

I want to triple integrate f($p_1, p_2, p_3$) over the following criteria:

$$\begin{align*}
p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 &= 1\\
p_1 + p_2 + p_3 &\le 1\\
p_1 &> p_2\\
p_1 &> p_3\\
p_1 &\ge 0\\
p_2 &\ge 0\\
p_3 &\ge 0\\
p_4 &\ge 0
\end{align*}$$

Can someone tell me what should be the limits of my triple integral and in which order f($p_1, p_2, p_3$) should be integrated?

Comment: Generally, you can do integrals like these in two ways: you can define a region `reg = ImplicitRegion[...]` (or other valid region object) that satisfies the constraints and then call `Integrate` using this region as `Integrate[f[p1,p2,p3,p4], {p1, p2, p3, p4} \[Element] reg]`. The other way is to include the constraints into the integrant by multiplying `f` with statements like `Boole[p1 > p3]` to make it zero in the places where you don't want to have a contribution. For the constraint `p1+p2+p3+p4 == 1`, you probably need a `DiracDelta`

Comment: Altho mef has already informed you about `DirichletDistribution[]`, you might nevertheless be interested in looking up `CylindricalDecomposition[]` for determining your integration bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Therefore, writing:

```
Reduce[p1 + p2 + p3 < 1 && p1 > p2 && p1 > p3 && p1 > 0 && p2 > 0 && p3 > 0]
```

you can also get the integration intervals.

Unfortunately, a simple analytical result doesn't seem to me to be able to get it.

Then, for example, writing:

```
f[b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_, x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := 
  p1^(b1 + x1 - 1) p2^(b2 + x2 - 1) p3^(b3 + x3 - 1) p4^(b4 + x4 - 1);

A := ImplicitRegion[p1 + p2 + p3 < 1 && p1 > p2 && p1 > p3 && 
                   p1 > 0 && p2 > 0 && p3 > 0, {p1, p2, p3}];

Integrate[f[1, 1, 1, 1, p1, p2, p3, 1 - p1 - p2 - p3, 
            1, 1, 1, 1], {p1, p2, p3} \[Element] A]
```

I get:

> 1/15120

which is what you want.

Comment: You missed the condition $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 = 1$. And how can you get the integration result without the values of x1, x2, b1, b2, etc.?

Comment: $p_i$s are vote shares for party i. The joint probability distribution function is available. I want to calculate the probability when party 1 beats party 2 and party 3. The criteria there is $p_1 > p_2$ and $p_1 > p_3$. Also, sum of vote shares for these 3 parties will be less than equal to 1, i.e. $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \leq 1$. And the sum of all vote shares should be 1, i.e. $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 =1$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Dirichlet distribution, but you have omitted the constant of integration. For simplicity, let $a_i = b_i + x_i$. The density function for this distribution is given by

```
PDF[DirichletDistribution[{a1, a2, a3, a4}], {p1, p2, p3}]
```

In order to find the limits of integration that respect your additional constraints, it is convenient to work with a specialized parameter vector where $a_i = 1$. In this case the pdf is flat over the simplex. Before finding the proper limits, first note

```
Integrate[
  PDF[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 1}], {p1, p2, p3}], 
  {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}
]
(* 1 *)
```

Now for the limits that respect the additional constraints (i.e., $p_1 > p_2$ and $p_1 > p_3$):

```
Integrate[
  PDF[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 1}], {p1, p2, p3}], 
  {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, p1}, {p3, 0, p1}
]
(* 1/3 *)
```

We may run a simulation to check the reasonableness of this result:

```
Count[
   RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 1}], 10^5],
   {p1_, p2_, p3_} /; p1 > p2 && p1 > p3
   ]/10^5 // N
(* 0.3307 *)
```

The analytical result seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
RegionPlot3D[p1+p2+p3<=1 && p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>=0 && p2>=0 && p3>=0,
  {p1,0,1}, {p2,0,1}, {p3,0,1}, PlotPoints->100, AxesLabel->{p1,p2,p3}]
```

shows the five sided prism that your viable points live inside. From that you can see the viable ranges for p2 and p3. I believe that p4 is implicitly represented in that diagram.

This then does your integral, but only including your first factor.

```
Assuming[x1>0 && x2>0 && x3>0 && x4>0 && b1>0 && b2>0 && b3>0 && b4>0, 
 Simplify[Integrate[Boole[p1+p2+p3<=1 && p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>=0 && p2>=0 && p3>=0]*
   p1^(b1+x1-1),
   {p1,0,1}, {p2,0,1/2}, {p3,0,1/2}]]]
```

As you incorporate your additional factors the result is bigger and much slower until it finally can't give you a simple closed form without additional information about your parameters.

```
Assuming[x1>0 && x2>0 && x3>0 && x4>0 && b1>0 && b2>0 && b3>0 && b4>0, 
 Simplify[Integrate[Boole[p1+p2+p3<=1 && p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>=0 && p2>=0 && p3>=0]*
   p1^(b1+x1-1) p2^(b2+x2-1) p3^(b3+x3-1)(1-p1-p2-p3)^(x4+b4-1),
   {p1,0,1}, {p2,0,1/2}, {p3,0,1/2}]]
```

If you incorporate the additional information about your parameters, perhaps even up to some or all of the numeric values, then I think this gives you the result that you are looking for.